# Dex bundled with ArgoCD, couldnt connect with GITLAB

Tags: devops, argocd

```
url: https://<myproxy_Cloudflare_URL>/api/dex/callback
dex.config: |
  connectors:
    - type: gitlab
      id: gitlab
      name: GitLab
      config:
        clientID: <ID>
        clientSecret: <Secret>
```

This is my config added to Configmap of argocd Dex section so what's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you don't have to specify url: https://<myproxy_Cloudflare_URL>/api/dex/callback in "url" section this will be your redirectURI section and if you look at the argocd official document you dont even need to mention redirectURI, can you try using that and if issue still persists, you can share logs

Answer (score 0):

Please change the url as per the [argocd Documention](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/operator-manual/user-management/#sso).

```
url: https://<myproxy_Cloudflare_URL>
```